# Solving the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{y+2xy^2}{3x^2y^2+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we find the solutions to the differential equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{y+2xy^3}{3x^2y^2+x}$$
It is not homogeneous, neither is it a Bernoulli differential equation.

I have no idea how to find $y$. Hints and answers appreciated.

Comment: Compute the derivative of $x^2y(x)^3+xy(x)$.

Comment: It looks like the top and bottom are the first derivatives of the same polynomial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write ir as
$$
(y+2xy^3)dx+(3x^2y^2+x)dy=0.
$$
It is exact.